# Position absolute element in center of free space

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website. The website has a header with navbar and logo. Under the header there is a picture-slider.
Now to my problem: The logo has a `position: absolute` and the parent container a `position: relative` to let the logo look into the slider. Now I want the logo to be in centered at resize between the left window border and the navbar.

If I do something with `%` it doesn't resize automatically. How to do this?

```
<div class="container" style="postion:relative; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
    <div class="header-logo" style="position: absolute; height:100%; width:auto;">
        <img class="logo" src="logo.png" style="width:80%; margin-left:50%"> 
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar" style="margin-top:10px;">
     ...
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="slider">
 ...
</div>
```

---

UPDATE 1:

```
<div class="container">

    <img class="logo" src="logo.png" style="float: left; width:10%; margin-left:5%; margin-bottom:-100px"> 

    <nav class="navbar" style="margin-top:10px;">
     ...
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="slider">
 ...
</div>
```

---

[image: example]

Comment: _“Please assist.”_ - please go read [ask] and [mre], and show what you got so far. We are not here to write code for you, based on you putting in no more effort than holding up a picture.

Comment: @AutMai Add your code to problem. Otherwise can,t help anyone.

Comment: I added this part of code.

Comment: I don't understand why in the world would you want the logo to be position absolute.

Comment: I thought for reaching into the slider, is there another method, how to to this?

Comment: You can use a negative margin

Comment: There's a typo in the first line of the code you posted, the word "position" is misspelled.

Comment: I did an "UPDATE 1" edit | Now i just need the centering of the logo - do I need an event listener on resize or is this possible with css only?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the margin-left of the image to 10% (since the width you assigned is 80%, there is 20% remaining for both sides, left and right).